# C# Class inheritance, interface and instantiation

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a base class that looks like this

```
public class CamelClient : ICamelClient
{
    protected HttpClient _Client { get; set; }

    protected readonly string _BaseAddress;

    protected readonly string _TokenEndpoint;

    protected readonly string _ClientId;

    protected readonly string _Secret;

    public Contacts Contacts { get; set; }

    public Auth Auth { get; set; }

    public CamelClient(string baseAddress, string tokenEndpoint, string clientId, string secret)
    {
        _BaseAddress = baseAddress;
        _TokenEndpoint = tokenEndpoint;
        _ClientId = clientId;
        _Secret = secret;

        _Client = new HttpClient();
        _Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_BaseAddress);

        Auth = new Auth(_BaseAddress, _TokenEndpoint, _ClientId, _Secret);
        Contacts = new Contacts(_BaseAddress, _TokenEndpoint, _ClientId, _Secret);
    }
}
```

It has an interface which looks like this

```
public interface ICamelClient
{
    Contacts Contacts { get; set; }

    Auth Auth { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is when Contacts and Auth get instantiated in the base class constructor I get an infinite loop because the derived classes call the base constructor and eventually I get a stack overflow error.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work because if I don't instantiate the Contacts and Auth classes it works but when I try and use then they are null?

The Contact class looks like this

```
public class Contacts : CamelClient
{
    public Contacts(string baseAddress, string tokenEndpoint, string clientId, string secret) : base(baseAddress, tokenEndpoint, clientId, secret)
    {
    }
}
```

And the Auth class looks like this

```
public class Auth : CamelClient
{
    public Auth(string baseAddress, string tokenEndpoint, string clientId, string secret) : base(baseAddress, tokenEndpoint, clientId, secret)
    {
    }
}
```

Changed my code and it seems to work now.

```
public class CamelClient : ICamelClient
{
    public HttpClient _Client { get; set; }

    public readonly string _BaseAddress;

    public readonly string _TokenEndpoint;

    public readonly string _ClientId;

    public readonly string _Secret;

    public Contacts Contacts { get; }

    public Auth Auth { get; }

    public CamelClient(string baseAddress, string tokenEndpoint, string clientId, string secret)
    {
        _BaseAddress = baseAddress;
        _TokenEndpoint = tokenEndpoint;
        _ClientId = clientId;
        _Secret = secret;

        _Client = new HttpClient();
        _Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_BaseAddress);

        Auth = new Auth(this);
        Contacts = new Contacts(this);
    }

public interface ICamelClient
{
    Contacts Contacts { get; }

    Auth Auth { get; }
}

 public class Auth
{
    private readonly CamelClient _CamelClient;

    public Auth(CamelClient camelClient) => _CamelClient = camelClient;
}

public class Contacts
{
    private readonly CamelClient _CamelClient;

    public Contacts(CamelClient camelClient) => _CamelClient = camelClient;
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that we could copy and paste into a console app to reproduce the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I think there's an implication in this question that you've forgotten to make explicit. Are `Contacts` and `Auth` classes that *derive* from `CamelClient`? If so, please actually mention that in the question.

Comment: How do the `Auth`- and the `Contancts`-class look like? Why does instantuiating them call the constructor of `CamelClient`, unless they derive from the latter class? Could you please post the code for those classes also? Furthermore: if they really derive from `CamelClient`, why should an instance of `Auth` have an `Auth`-member also? It seems your inheritance-chain is somehow broken.

Comment: Have updated my question with the Auth and Contact derived classes.

Comment: Why does a `Contacts` object have a `Contacts` property?

Comment: @mjwills I wanted to use this like CamelClient.Contacts.AnyMethod();

Comment: Your problem is a faulty class design, the infinite loop is only a symptom. Your CamelClient is a repository, that is sort of Ok. But then your model says _"a Contact IS a CamelClient"_. Which makes no sense.

Comment: Only because you need a method in another class is a bad reason to let it derive from the class that contains that method. Instead you should create a third class that contains that method and have a dependency to that class in both your `CamleClient` and your `Auth`- and `Contacts`-classes.

Comment: `I wanted to use this like CamelClient.Contacts.AnyMethod();` What about `CamelClient.Contacts.Auth.Contacts.Auth.Contacts.AnyMethod()`? That will compile, with your existing inheritance structure. But what should it **do**?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. My problem is the design. I am going to rework this taking into account what has been said/suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're creating some recursive data structures (if my assumption that `Contacts` and `Auth` derive from `CamelClient` is correct).

In such a case, and if you believe that this is correctly modelled<sup>1</sup>, I'd probably change the `Contacts` and `Auth` properties to be read-only properties back by a *lazy-initialized* backing field. This can be as simple as:

```
public class CamelClient : ICamelClient
{
    //...

    private Contacts _contacts;

    public Contacts Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            if(_contacts == null)
            {
                _contacts = new Contacts(_BaseAddress, _TokenEndpoint, _ClientId, _Secret);
            }
            return _contacts;
        }
    }
```

And the same for `Auth`. This isn't thread-safe though. If you want that, I'd probably recommend that the backing field use [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) and have that appropriate initialized in the constructor

---

<sup>1</sup>It seems questionable, in this circumstance, that a consumer can do `a.Auth.Auth.Contacts.Auth.Contacts.Contacts.Auth...`, and so on, on any given instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I agree with you and don't think my design is very good. Do you perhaps have a suggestion/example to improve this?

Comment: @Jebanisa - it would seem that `Contacts` and `Auth` might more properly be modelled as *owned* by the `CamelClient` class - they will have a *reference* to their owner and access *its* `BaseAddress`, etc properties by making appropriate changes to the accessibility. (Note that this type of relationship can also be described as parent/child but note that this is *not* the same kind of parent/child terminology often used to describe inheritance families, which is what you've currently modelled)

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you are saying. Thank you.